# find number of '*.xls' files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
path='E:\Practice'; 
folder = path; 
dirListing = dir(folder); 

for i=1:length(dirListing); 
Data{i}=dirListing(i,1).name; 
f{i} = fullfile(path, Data{i}); 
end
```

Which lists the folder names, and gives the path of each folder individually.

I am now trying to find the number of .xls files in each path denoted by 'f'. I've attempted:

```
for i=1:length(f) 
    files{i}=dir(fullfile(path,f(i),'*.xls')); 
end
```

but an error appears. Does anyone know how this can be done?

cheers

Comment: change `f(i)` to `f{i}` in `files{i}=dir(fullfile(path,f{i},'*.xls')); `

Comment: @cyborg: You should post it as answer. Probably also adding how to count the found files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would `length(dir([path '\*.xls']));` do what you're looking for? I included the slash so it's a path, but you could easily replace that with the [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html) function

Answer (score -1):

try this hopefully it does what you want

```
files=[];
for i=1:length(f) 
    if(strcmp(f{i}(end-2:end),'xls'))
            files{end+1}=f{i}
    end
end
```